# Kubuntu 16.04 login lockout

Tags: 16.04, updates, kubuntu, login, password

Yesterday I updated my Dell Latitude D650 laptop with the new LTS edition of Kubuntu, v.16.04.  I was previously running the 14.04 LTS release. After completing the update and restarting the computer, I was given a black terminal screen with the prompt `Login:_` instead of the normal user-account login screen with picture icons for accounts.

I've tried logging in as my username, Administrator, Root, and anything else I can think of, and tried as many different plausible password combinations as i can and it always comes back with a `invalid login` message.

Please, somebody tell me there is a way to unlock my computer so I don't have to wipe it and start over? I was never prompted to change any login settings in the update process...